# Change the color of the bar chart based on range value

Tags: c#, charts, chart.js, blazor, blazor-webassembly

How can I change the color of the bar in the chart according to the value range?

Example:
I'm using the Blazor WebAssembly App project with the chart package -*PSC.Blazor.Components.Chartjs -Version 6.0.40*.

I want to change the bar and border color to:

- Green if `Value` is 0-1.25,
- Orange if `Value` is 1.25-2.5
- Red if `Value` is 2.5-3.75
- Black if `Value` is 3.75-5.

Here is my Model code:

```cs
public class DataItem
{
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("value")]
    public decimal? Value { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("bordercolor")]
    public string? BorderColor { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("backgroundcolor")]
    public string? BackgroundColor { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my data code:

```cs
public class BarDataExample
{
    public static List<DataItem> SimpleBar = new List<DataItem>() 
    {
        new DataItem() { Name = "Info", Value = 1.0m, BackgroundColor="", BorderColor=""},
        new DataItem() { Name = "Org", Value = 1.0m, BackgroundColor="", BorderColor="" },
        new DataItem() { Name = "HR", Value = 1.4m, BackgroundColor="", BorderColor="" },
        new DataItem() { Name = "AM", Value = 2.4m, BackgroundColor="", BorderColor="" },
        new DataItem() { Name = "Acc", Value = 2.0m, BackgroundColor="", BorderColor="" },
        new DataItem() { Name = "Cryp", Value = 5.6m, BackgroundColor="", BorderColor="" },
        new DataItem() { Name = "Phy", Value = 3.0m, BackgroundColor="", BorderColor="" },
        new DataItem() { Name = "Oper", Value = 6.7m, BackgroundColor="", BorderColor="" },
        new DataItem() { Name = "Comm", Value = 6.9m, BackgroundColor="", BorderColor="" },
        new DataItem() { Name = "Sys", Value = 3.8m, BackgroundColor="", BorderColor="" },
        new DataItem() { Name = "Sup", Value = 8.7m, BackgroundColor="", BorderColor="" },
        new DataItem() { Name = "Sec", Value = 7.5m, BackgroundColor="", BorderColor="" },
        new DataItem() { Name = "Busi", Value = 8.5m, BackgroundColor="", BorderColor="" },
        new DataItem() { Name = "Legal", Value = 7.9m, BackgroundColor="", BorderColor="" } 
    };
}
```

Here is my razor code:

```
@page "/horizontalbar"

@using BlazorCharts.Data;

<h3>HorizontalBar</h3>

<Chart Config="_config1" @ref="_chart1" Height="400px"></Chart>

@code {
private BarChartConfig? _config1;
private Chart? _chart1;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _config1 = new BarChartConfig()
    {
        Options = new Options()
        {
            IndexAxis = "y",
            Responsive = true,
            MaintainAspectRatio = false,
            Plugins = new Plugins()
            {
                Legend = new Legend()
                {
                    Align = Align.Center,
                    Display = false,
                    Position = LegendPosition.Right
                }
            },
            Scales = new Dictionary<string, Axis>()
            {
                {
                    Scales.XAxisId, new Axis()
                    {
                        Stacked = true,
                        Ticks = new Ticks()
                        {
                            MaxRotation = 0,
                            MinRotation = 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    Scales.YAxisId, new Axis()
                    {
                        Stacked = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    _config1.Data.Labels = BarDataExample.SimpleBar.Select(e => e.Name).ToList();
    _config1.Data.Datasets.Add(new BarDataset()
        {
            Label = "Value",
            Data = BarDataExample.SimpleBar.Select(l => l.Value).ToList(),
            BackgroundColor = new List<string>() { "#ccff99", "#ff9999", "#ffcc80", 
                      "#a6a6a6" },
            BorderColor = new List<string>() { "#2eb82e", "#e60000", "#e68a00", 
                      "#404040" },
            BorderWidth = 1

        });
}
}
```

Here I have mentioned the color manually, but the border and background color has to be changed based on the range I have given in the value. Since I'm a beginner in C#, I don't know how to pull this. Do help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Iterate each element in `BarDataExample.SimpleBar` array, and assign each element's `BackgroundColor` and `BorderColor` values according to `dataItem.Value.Value`.
2. Select the values of `BackgroundColor` and `BorderColor` from the `BarDataExample.SimpleBar` and assign them to the config for `BackgroundColor` and `BorderColor` of `BarDataset` instance respectively.

```cs
foreach (var dataItem in BarDataExample.SimpleBar)
{
    if (dataItem.Value.HasValue)
    {
        if (dataItem.Value.Value >= (decimal)0m
            && dataItem.Value.Value < (decimal)1.25m)
        {
            dataItem.BackgroundColor = "#008000";
            dataItem.BorderColor = "#008000";
        }
        else if (dataItem.Value.Value >= (decimal)1.25m
            && dataItem.Value.Value < (decimal)2.5m)
        {
            dataItem.BackgroundColor = "#FFA500";
            dataItem.BorderColor = "#FFA500";
        }
        else if (dataItem.Value.Value >= (decimal)2.5
            && dataItem.Value.Value < (decimal)3.75m)
        {
            dataItem.BackgroundColor = "#ff0000";
            dataItem.BorderColor = "#ff0000";
        }
        else if (dataItem.Value.Value >= (decimal)3.75m
            && dataItem.Value.Value < (decimal)5m)
        {
            dataItem.BackgroundColor = "#000000";
            dataItem.BorderColor = "#000000";
        }
        else
        {
            dataItem.BackgroundColor = "#D3D3D3";
            dataItem.BorderColor = "#D3D3D3";
        }
    }
}

_config1.Data.Datasets.Add(new BarDataset()
{
    Label = "Value",
    Data = BarDataExample.SimpleBar.Select(l => l.Value).ToList(),
    BackgroundColor = BarDataExample.SimpleBar.Select(l => l.BackgroundColor).ToList(),
    BorderColor = BarDataExample.SimpleBar.Select(l => l.BorderColor).ToList(),
    BorderWidth = 1
});
```

> Demo

[image]